# django, fastcgi, throws random 404 errors

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, fastcgi

I have a django website deployed on a shared webhost. The shared webhost uses fastcgi.
I'm noticing that valid urls will randomly throw up http404 but as soon as I refresh will work again.
does anyone know why this may be?

*** Update ***
Sys admins have culled logs for me and I think the following logs are examples of what is being generated by the issue:

> Mon Oct 03 12:53:37 2011] [warn] [client *my ip*] (104)Connection
>   reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server,
>   referer: *valid url on site*
>   [Mon Oct 03 12:53:37 2011] [error] [client *my ip*] Premature end of
>   script headers: fs.fcgi, referer:
>   *valid url on site*

all my googling only turned up issues that should always happen. not random, sporadic occurrences.
any suggestions?

Comment: do you have access to logs ?

Comment: @ascobol kind of. shared host so rely on sys admins to cull them for me. new information in post

Answer (score 1):

I had this same fault but my config is different - Django behind uWSGI, behind Nginx.

However, in my case, it was cured simply be restarting the uswgi service:

```
$ sudo service uwsgi restart
```

Job done. I know this is an old question and I'm amazed to be only the 2nd person to have the problem in 5 years - but hopefully this will help someone :)